# Linux command to DOS

Tags: linux, dos

I have a file include some linux command and I want to run in on windows (DOS command).
The command is:

```
cat tmp/$id/index.html | sed -e 's/ID/$id/g' > a;mv a tmp/$id/index.html
```

What is the similar command in MS-DOS? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that natively there is no equivalent command to sed. You have two options from my point of view. Either create a vb script that does what you want (It will not take 1 line though - more like 10-15 I guess), or use something like [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) that gives you the option to run unix commands in windows terminal.

Comment: Cygwin uses its own terminal and you have to use that. I don't know about mingw if it the same (I have never tried it).

GnuWin32 though runs in cmd.exe

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using powershell to do approximately the same thing. It supports `cat` and `mv` and you can get a `sed` like equivalent by using `%{_ -replace "expression", "replace"}`. Details here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2007/07/09/grep-and-sed-with-powershell.aspx

Or consider using a linux like command prompt like bash which should be available through cygwin

Answer (score 0):

I think this is impossible to do in "bare" command line (as you called DOS command), because cat and sed are separate utilities. If you want to port this script from Linux command shell to windows command line, I would advise you to download and install [CygWin](http://cygwin.com)

Answer (score 0):

DOS itself does not have support for that. You could try with a port of SED for DOS [available here](http://sed.sourceforge.net/). If you can get [Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/powershell.aspx), that's an option. [Here's an example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2007/07/09/grep-and-sed-with-powershell.aspx) of using grep/sed with Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options.

You can try to install [cygwin](https://cygwin.com) or [download  and install Git](https://git-scm.com/download/win) and use Git-bash or add the bin directory to your PATH so you can run this command on your CMD prompt.

Answer (score -1):

There is no such command(s) for MS-DOS.